# Need Message composer Behaviour same as like in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone 8 app.

In windows phone 8 when we want to send new text by clicking on the "+"(new) icon screen appears as To: and with plus icon to add the contacts and message textbox to send the message with default focus at To: when we type a text it searches and displays the contacts below in a list when we select any contact it places ";" after each contact and we can add multiple contacts to send the message to all.

And when we try to clear the content after ";" it will clear the whole text.

By clicking on the contact selected it is redirected to another page of the particular contact with "open", "remove", "copy", "cancel"..

I need the same exact functionality in my project as we are providing the messaging behaviour in my app.I had collections of my contacts....I had seen "AutoCompleteBox" in this [link](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/autocompletebox-for-wp7-in-depth) but i does not allow to select multiple contacts.. can we implement this.. i had seen "auto complete box" in telerik also same prob.How can we select multiple contacts, clear functionality with semi colon and make them clickable same as in windows phone 8....   Can any one please help me to solve my problem....